# Add Application Insight to a existing Azure Service Fabric cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

We have been working on Azure Service Fabric since last 4 months but now have decided to have a unified loging infrastructure for which we are using AppInsight, how can we add a AppInsight Key to a existing Service Fabric cluster

Comment: Hi, 
I have a similar requirement , Is it configurable now, what did you do to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 5):

I did it this way, using **Visual Studio 2017**:

1. Open **Cloud Explorer** from **VS**
2. Expand **Virtual Machine Scale Sets**
3. Locate the scale set containing your SF cluster.
4. Right-click **Update diagnostics...**
5. In the dialog, check **Send diagnostics to Application Insights** and add the **Instrumentation key** for you AI sink
6. Click **OK** and leave the dialogue
7. You might get an error (I did), but if you re-open the dialog you will find that the settings are still there.
8. To 'apply' the new settings to the cluster, open your azure portal, select **All resources**, and open the **Virtual Machine Scale Set**
9. At this point, hopefully selecting **Restart** will apply the changes to the cluster. I did a **Deallocate** followed by a **Restart** and a re-deploy of my SF-application, and this worked (I did not test if just doing a restart would work). However be very careful using this approach, make sure you know the trade-offs when de-allocation a SF-cluster

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it is not just that simple right now.

The Application Insights support as [shown at Build 2017](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/P4113) is still in preview. It consists of two nuget preview packages you have to install and you need to update your cluster to the latest version. Stay tuned to [this](https://github.com/qubitron/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/blob/master/ApplicationInsights.md) repo which at the moment shows

> Using Service Fabric with Application Insights
>
> We are working on updating this repo to demonstrate how to use Service Fabric with Application Insights.
> The completed repo is not quite ready, please check back here within the next couple of days!

More information about the setup and nuget packages can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric/blob/develop/README.md):

> This repository produces the following two nuget packages:
>
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native - For use with Service Fabric's native reliable services.
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric - For use with Guest Executable and Guest container services (lift and shift scenarios).

Until that time you can take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/DeHeerSoftware/Azure-Service-Fabric-Logging-And-Monitoring) for full (manual) Application Insights integration.

Comment: Any update on this after 9 months? This is what I'm trying to do right now.