# Using PowerShell to add Application insights to Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights, azure-powershell

Is there a PowerShell option to add Application insights to Service Fabric? In the documentation, [How to enable Application Insights Profiler on Azure Compute resources](https://github.com/CawaMS/EnableProfilerForCompute/blob/master/How%20to%20enable%20Application%20Insights%20Profiler%20on%20Azure%20Compute%20resources.md), there is ARM template snippet:

```
             "SinksConfig": {
               "Sink": [
                 {
                   "name": "MyApplicationInsightsProfilerSinkVMSS",
                   "ApplicationInsightsProfiler": "[Application_Insights_Key]"
                 }
               ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Application Insight to a existing Azure Service Fabric cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018499/add-application-insight-to-a-existing-azure-service-fabric-cluster)

Comment: no exactly I am looking for a powershell option not a UI VS solution.